# Sonos Control Api: Get sonos account information

Tags: sonos

I am integrating Sonos using Control API.

In the login phase, the user writes username and password in the Sonos login page and authorizes the integration.
After that Sonos returns an authorization code back to my integration to use for calling api.

I would like to display the username in my application. How can you get it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there aren't any publicly-available APIs for getting the user information you are looking for. Given the sensitivity of any type of user information, we don't have any plans to expose APIs for getting this information in the near future.

The closest thing to a user unique identifier would be a householdId. This is documented here: https://developer.sonos.com/reference/control-api/households/.

Thanks,

-Mark

Comment: Thanks for the answer